# When does fork choice really checked in Ethereum2.0?

Tags: fork-choice-rule

I have a question about when the fork-choice rule is checked in real implementation or in the specification.
Maintaining a fork-choice store is important and due to network delay, there may happen temporal fork. In this case, as I understand, the fork-choice rule (i.e., in this case, LMD-GHOST) decides the canonical head (simply the most voted block win).

1. When a validator receives any new unaggregated/aggregated attestation

   - This may require too much computation
2. When a validator receives a new beacon block

   - e.g., during per-block processing
3. When a validator became a proposer
4. When slot/epoch starts or ends

   - e.g., during per-slot/epoch processing